# select latest (up to some date ) records of each variable from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

example of a table structure

```
VarName   Date   Machine
-------------------------
A    date1       machine1
B    date2       machine1
A    date3       machine2
C    date4       machine2
A    date5       machine1
C    date6       machine1
A    date7       machine1
```

What I am trying to filter from my database should look like this:

```
  VarName   Date   Machine
    -------------------------
    A    date1       machine1
    B    date2       machine1
    C    date6       machine1
```

Every variable has to be selected only once and each variable must be the latest record up to a certain date. My statement conditions are (`WHERE date <= 'some date' AND machine='SomeMachineName'`). Join statement is probably the solution but I had no luck with anything I'd tried.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.varname = t.varname and
                      t2.date <= @date
               );
```

For performance, you want an index on `t(varname, date)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Have a derived table (the sub-query) that returns each VarName's last date. Join with that result:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select VarName, max(Date) Date
      from tablename
      group by VarName) t2
  on t1.Varname = t2.VarName and t1.Date = t2.Date
```

Comment: You're missing a `WHERE` clause, see Gordon's answer.  Hence the importance of taking the time to make sure your answer is correct before posting :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Yes, and also one of the reasons why OP should post a query attempt...

Comment: @jarlh or perhaps a reason why we should resist posting answers until adequate information is provided!